# ionic 3 provider initialization on ionViewDidLoad

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

First of  all, sorry if my english isn't perfect, I'm french.

I'm creating a mobil app with Ionic 3 / angular 4.

My data are stored in a local JSON file in "assets/data" and I'm accessing it with a Provider.
I have a homePage with formular with data value for my 'selector/option input' and I request my provider which returns data by filter/sort etc ...

Everything works but ... it's kind of ugly.
For now, I'm actually using a button at the top of my form to initialize my Provider because I'm calling the 'http.get' method in my Provider constructor (Yeah ... I know it's kind of bad).

I'm using this temporary solution while waiting to find a way to initialize my Provider on the splash screen or in 'ionViewDidLoad' Event ...

my Provider constructor :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataBaseProvider {
  capaciteUrl = './assets/data/capacite.json';
  mixageUrl = "./assets/data/mixage.json";
  mixageData: any;
  capaciteData: any;

constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('dataBase init');
    this.http.get(this.capaciteUrl)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe( data => this.capaciteData = data.data);
    this.http.get(this.mixageUrl)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe( data => this.mixageData = data.data);
  }
```

my 'initializer' function in my homePage.ts ( called by button )

```
init() {
    this.dataBase.getDataSelector()
      .then(data => {
        this.mixage = data['mixage'];
        this.capacite = data['capacite'];
        this.firstIngredient = this.secondIngredient = data['ingredient'];
      })
  }
```

A part of my form :

```
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="mixageSelector" okText="Select">
<ion-option *ngFor="let mix of mixage" [value]="mix.id"> {{mix.name}} </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Where can I call the Http.get method or How can I rewrite my module to call Http method at loading/splashScreen of my application ? ( I also try to call my getDataSelector() in an ionViewDidLoadEvent() but nothing changes ... )

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem